# RegEX: Finding any two words on their own line ending in :

Tags: regex

Given this body of text:

```
First Citizen:
Before we proceed any further, hear me speak.
What authority surfeits on would relieve us:
Speak, speak.
ALL:
You are all resolved rather to die than to famish?
```

I would like to match:

```
['First Citizen', 'ALL']
```

I originally tried something like this `r'([\w -:]*:)'` but want to limit it to lines with only 2 words.

Specifications:

- Line ends with :
- Line only has two words or less
- match those one or two words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any word: `\w+`

Any two words (with whitespace): `\w+\s\w+`

Any two words or less (assuming one, not zero): `\w+(?:\s\w+)?`

Any two words or less on their own line: `^\w+(?:\s\w+)?$`

Any two words or less on their own line ending in ":": `^\w+(?:\s\w+)?:$`

The result in (Python) code:

```
import re

text = """
First Citizen:
Before we proceed any further, hear me speak.
What authority surfeits on would relieve us:
Speak, speak.
ALL:
You are all resolved rather to die than to famish?
"""

for match in re.findall(r"^\w+(?:\s\w+)?:$", text, re.MULTILINE):
    print(match)
```

The output:

```
First Citizen:
ALL:
```

You didn't specify a language, so your language may need one or two parameters to deal with the regex in the right way.

Comment: I'd reduce the third to `\w(\s\w+)?:`, personally. But it shows a good variety for sure

Comment: You're right that `(?:\s\w+)?` could be reduced to `(\s\w+)?` for the same result here, although I make a habit of marking groups as non-capturing unless I actually want them to to capture. I'm not aware of any overhead from the added `?:` and if there are many matches, there may even be a bit of a performance advantage depending on the engine